# How can I indicate the entry id in the Logstash script?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following mapping in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "regions": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      }, 
      "properties": {
          "regionid": {"type": "keyword"},
          "seasons": { 
              "properties": {
                  "season-type":  { "type": "keyword" },
                  "period": { 
                    "properties": {
                      "start-day":  { "type": "integer" },
                      "start-month":  { "type": "integer" },
                      "end-day":  { "type": "integer" },
                      "end-month":  { "type": "integer" }
                    }
                  }
             }
            },
            "autonomous_communities": {
                "properties": {
                      "autonomous_community":  { "type": "keyword" },
                      "codified_autonomous_community":  { "type": "keyword" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I save some input data as follows:

```
PUT myindex/regions/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"regionid":"1", "seasons":[{"season-type":"Type1","start-day":10,"start-month":1,"end-day":31,"end-month":5},{"season-type":"Type2","start-day":1,"start-month":9,"end-day":9,"end-month":1},{"season-type":"Type3","start-day":1,"start-month":6,"end-day":30,"end-month":9}]}
```

However the field `autonomous_communities` should be filled from CSV file, because it contains a large array. So, I use the following Logstash script to add data into `autonomous_communities_shapefile`.

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/path/to/CSV/file.csv"]
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

filter {  
    csv {
        columns => ["autonomous_community","codified_autonomous_community"]
        separator => ","
    }
    if [col1] == "autonomous_community" {
    drop {}
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "myindex"
        document_type => "autonomous_communities"
        workers => 1
    }
}
```

How can I indicate the corresponding `regionid` in the Logstash script? Imagine that I have 10 entries with `regionid` from 1 to 10. So, my current CSV file refers to `regionid` equal to 1.

My objective is to see the following result in Elasticsearch after running Logstash script:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "regions",
        "_id": "1",
        {"regionid":"1", 
         "seasons":[{"season-type":"Type1","start-day":10,"start-month":1,"end-day":31,"end-month":5},{"season-type":"Type2","start-day":1,"start-month":9,"end-day":9,"end-month":1},{"season-type":"Type3","start-day":1,"start-month":6,"end-day":30,"end-month":9}],      
         "autonomous_communities":[{"autonomous_community":"XXX","codified_autonomous_community":"AAA"},{"autonomous_community":"YYY","codified_autonomous_community":"BBB"}]
         }
  }
]
```

But currently I get something like this:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "regions",
        "_id": "1",
        {"regionid":"1", 
         "seasons":[{"season-type":"Type1","start-day":10,"start-month":1,"end-day":31,"end-month":5},{"season-type":"Type2","start-day":1,"start-month":9,"end-day":9,"end-month":1},{"season-type":"Type3","start-day":1,"start-month":6,"end-day":30,"end-month":9}],      
  },
  {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "regions",
        "_id": "345864068",      
        "autonomous_community":"XXX",
        "codified_autonomous_community":"AAA"
  },
  {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "regions",
        "_id": "57934753670,      
        "autonomous_community":"YYY",
        "codified_autonomous_community":"BBB"
   }
]
```